# Type of Ground Wire for an AM Crystal Radio - I'm using a longwire antenna

Tags: antenna, am, crystal-radio

I have way too many choices for ground wire.   I am using a crystal radio so I need the BEST not just what will 'get by'.   I've seen solid copper 10gauge,  aluminum wire etc.  I've also seen wide flat Braided tin coated copper braids. This looks like it has more 'surface area'?

My scientist side says we should use the braid from my radio, through the window and down to the Ground rod.  (more surface area)  Is that a safe bet?  And I'm going to use a 'regular' cheapie wire to run under the horizontal long wire tied to ground as a counterpoise.

Appreciate any information.

Comment: Back in my day I just connected a wire (whatever wire, it wasn't important) to a copper pipe.  These days you can't rely on pipes being grounded, but the more important point is that you're not going to be carrying any current to speak of and losses aren't a big issue at < 1MHz.

Comment: To clarify, are you talking about the ground electrode itself, or the conductor that connects the radio *to* the ground system? I think different people are answering different things.

Comment: The type of wire doesn't matter as long as it is conductive.  It matters more that it is tuned.  The best antenna I've seen for a crystal radio was a tuned multiturn loop.

Answer (score 2):

The use of 2.5 mm wire is enough, in a grounded rod at least 2 meters.

Comment: +1. A ground rod or pipe *in moist soil*.

Answer (score 0):

Back in the 1950s, I grounded my crystal radio (made with a new-fangled 1N34 diode) by connecting to the center screw of any outlet plate with a piece of hookup wire. Worked great!